# What's the connection between "kicking a pigeon" and "how a bill becomes a law"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

American television sitcom - Friends

> A: That man across the street just kicked that pigeon.
>
> B: And basically, that's how a bill becomes a law. (Along with audience laughing)

I looked up "kick pigeon" and "bill becomes law", found nothing.

Comment: Good question. I found [the episode script](http://uncutfriendsepisodes.tripod.com/season1/120uncut.htm) and read the whole scene. It's clearly meant to be a joke - and _Friends_ had a lot of corny jokes - but I don't get it. I haven't seen the episode, so maybe there's some crucial visual context missing. My best guess is that Chandler is referring to his "rule" about waiting to call women after a date, but I don't get the pigeon connection either.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> There is no connection. They are talking about Rachel and then she walks in, so Chandler pretends to be continuing a conversation about something totally different. (from a comment by [Minty](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/96060/minty))

Comment: And it's funny because the process of how a bill becomes a law is *not* something the friends would usually talk about. It's a very mundane thing to choose to cover up a prior conversation, which is funny.